# How do I conditionally map only the empty rows of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

how could I create a new dataframe column that maps to a dictionary, but only for blank rows, while retaining the values of a referenced column for non-blank rows? Below i've created 'new col' by mapping 'col1' to x, but I am looking to map to x only where 'col2' is empty and otherwise use the value in col2.

```
import pandas as pd
x = {'three':'green','four':'purple','five':'orange'}
d = {'col1': ['three', 'four', 'five'], 'col2':['blue',"","red"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['new col']=df['col1'].map(x)
```

actual result:

```
    col1  col2  new col
0   three blue   green
1   four         purple
2   five  red    orange
```

desired result (new col retains the values 'blue' and 'red' in rows 0 and 2, but maps row 1 to x):

```
    col1  col2   new col
0   three  blue  blue
1   four         purple
2   five    red  red
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `np.where`

```
df['newcol']=np.where(df.col2=='',df.col1.map(x),df.col2)
df
Out[607]: 
    col1  col2  newcol
0  three  blue    blue
1   four        purple
2   five   red     red
```

Comment: `df.col2.isnull()` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: `isnull()` won't detect empty strings, the equality check is necessary here

Comment: df.col2.isnull() is actually what worked for me ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `mask` and `fillna`:

```
df.col2.mask(df.col2.eq('')).fillna(df.col1.map(x))
```

```
0      blue
1    purple
2       red
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

---

```
df.assign(newcol=df.col2.mask(df.col2.eq('')).fillna(df.col1.map(x)))
```

```
    col1  col2  newcol
0  three  blue    blue
1   four        purple
2   five   red     red
```

#### An in-place option using `loc`:

This option is slower than both `np.where` and `mask`, but demonstrates clearly what we are doing.

```
df['newcol'] = df.col2
df.loc[df.col2.eq(''), 'newcol'] = df.col1.map(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html),

```
df['new col'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: x[row['col1']] if row['col2'] == '' else row['col2'], axis=1)
```